# Как взять только определённый JSON массив?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

Мне с сервера приходит `JSON` объект с `JSON` массивом `offers` и ненужным мне `JSON` объектом. Хочется взять только `offers` так, чтобы в интерфейсе API ретрофита можно было написать так:

```
Call<List<Offer>> offers();
```

Как это сделать? Пока что это сделано через класс

```
class OffersResponse {
     @SerializedName("offers")
     private Offer[] offers;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать кастомный `TypeAdapterFactory`, который будет вытаскивать массив из корневого объекта:

```
public class OffersAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement json = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (json.isJsonObject() && json.getAsJsonObject().has("offers")) {
                    json = json.getAsJsonObject().get("offers");
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(json);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

И зарегистрировать его при инициализации Retrofit:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new OffersAdapterFactory())
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        ...
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        ...
        .build();
```

И тогда ваш `Call<List<Offer>> offers();` корректно отработает.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я наконец-то понял как это работает)